# Find busiest period in building

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

**The task**

> You are given a list of data entries that represent entries and exits
>   of groups of people into a building. An entry looks like this:
>
> {"timestamp": 1526579928, count: 3, "type": "enter"}
>
> This means 3 people entered the building. An exit looks like this:
>
> {"timestamp": 1526580382, count: 2, "type": "exit"}
>
> This means that 2 people exited the building. timestamp is in Unix
>   time.
>
> Find the busiest period in the building, that is, the time with the
>   most people in the building. Return it as a pair of (start, end)
>   timestamps. You can assume the building always starts off and ends up
>   empty, i.e. with 0 people inside.

```
const stamp = [
  {"timestamp": 1526579928, count: 3, "type": "enter"},
  {"timestamp": 1526580382, count: 2, "type": "exit"},
  {"timestamp": 1526579938, count: 6, "type": "enter"},
  {"timestamp": 1526579943, count: 1, "type": "enter"},
  {"timestamp": 1526579944, count: 0, "type": "enter"},
  {"timestamp": 1526580345, count: 5, "type": "exit"},
  {"timestamp": 1526580351, count: 3, "type": "exit"},
];
```

**My imperative solution:**

```
const findBusiestPeriod = lst => {
  let visitors = 0;
  const busiestPeriod = {
    start: null,
    end: null,
    maxVisitors: null,
  };

  lst.forEach((v, i) => {
    visitors = v.type === "enter" ?
      visitors + v.count :
      visitors - v.count;

    if (visitors > busiestPeriod.maxVisitors) {
      busiestPeriod.maxVisitors = visitors;
      busiestPeriod.start = v.timestamp;
      busiestPeriod.end = lst[i + 1].timestamp;
    } else if (visitors === busiestPeriod.maxVisitors){
      busiestPeriod.end = lst[i + 1].timestamp;
    }
  });
  return [busiestPeriod.start, busiestPeriod.end];
};

console.log(findBusiestPeriod(stamp));
```

**My functional solution**

```
const findBusiestPeriod2 = lst => {
  const {start, end} = lst.reduce((busiestPeriod, v, i) => {
    busiestPeriod.visitors = v.type === "enter" ?
      busiestPeriod.visitors + v.count :
      busiestPeriod.visitors - v.count;
    const visitors = busiestPeriod.visitors;
    if (!busiestPeriod.maxVisitors || visitors > busiestPeriod.maxVisitors) {
      busiestPeriod.maxVisitors = visitors;
      busiestPeriod.start = v.timestamp;
      busiestPeriod.end = lst[i + 1].timestamp;
    } else if (visitors === busiestPeriod.maxVisitors){
      busiestPeriod.end = lst[i + 1].timestamp;
    }
    return busiestPeriod;
  }, {visitors: 0, maxVisitor: null,});
  return [start, end];
};

console.log(findBusiestPeriod2(stamp));
```

Comment: It sounds like Kadane's algorithm with some extra details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a short review;

- I advise avoiding `null`, you could either not define the member or use `undefined`
- `busiestPeriod` is a really long name, given how often you use it
- You really only need to track the log entry with the most visitors, the start of the period would be timestamp of the entry before that
- This: `busiestPeriod.visitors = v.type === "enter" ?
    busiestPeriod.visitors + v.count :
    busiestPeriod.visitors - v.count;` could be

  `busiestPeriod.visitors += (v.type == "enter" ? v.count : - v.count);`

  or even

  `busiestPeriod.visitors += (v.type == "enter" ? 1 : -1) * v.count;`

This is my counter-proposal:

```
function findBusiestTime(logs){

  function analyzeLogEntry(acc, log, index){
    if(log.type == "enter"){
      acc.count += log.count;   
    }else{
      if(acc.count > acc.maxCount){
        acc.maxCount = acc.count;
        acc.index = index;
      }
      acc.count -= log.count;
    }
    return acc;
  }

  let {index} = logs.reduce(analyzeLogEntry,{count:0, maxCount: 0});
  return [logs[index-1].timestamp,logs[index].timestamp];  
}
```

Comment: Why do you advice against using null?

Comment: There is little `null` can do that `undefined` can't do, to me it's like the appendix of JavaScript